# Pass promise to another function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

I would like to do something like this

```
function doSomething(aPromise) {
    if (/*xxx*/) {
        // doSomethingElse
    } else {
        return aPromise
            .then(doSomethingMore)
    }
}
```

However, if i do this, `aPromise` will always be executed when calling `doSomething`. How do i lazy execute it until it get called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `aPromise` as a function , returning `Promise` value from calling `aPromise()` at `else` block

```
function aPromise() {
  return Promise.resolve(/* `Promise` return value */)
}

function doSomething(aPromise) {
    if (/*xxx*/) {
        // doSomethingElse
    } else {
        // call `aPromise()` 
        return aPromise()
            .then(doSomethingMore)
    }
}
```